# PHPMailer simply hangs at the point of sending email

Tags: php, phpmailer

PHPMailer simply hangs at the point of sending email. I commented all code out line by line and everything worked fine until getting to

if(!$mail->send())

at which point the page goes into a spin - no error messages or any other indication of what has gone wrong. I think I have all of the required $mail-> entries

All of the files are located in the local home directory.

Full code below

I have been trying to get a mail agent running for 2 weeks - SMTP.js was originally used but then ceased working for reasons we don't know.

Any help to establish why PHPMailer hangs at this point would be greatly appreciated

```
?php
namespace MyProject;    

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

echo "uses done";


require 'vendor/autoload.php';

require_once 'PHPMailer.php';

require_once 'OAuth.php';

require_once 'Exception.php';

require_once 'SMTP.php';

require_once 'POP3.php';

echo "requires done";

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; //Alternative to above constant

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->SMTPDebug = true;

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = '****@gmail.com';

$mail->Password = '*****';

$mail->From = "****@****.org";

$mail->FromName = "RPI Registrations";

$mail->addAddress('*****n@**.com');

$mail->Subject = "RPI Examination Registration";

$mail->msgHTML('hello world');

$mail->addReplyTo("*****n@*****.org", "Reply");

echo "mail_composed";


//  $mail->addCC("cc@example.com");

//  $mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

$mail->isHTML(true);

// $mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";

// $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}



?>
```

Comment: you should steric **** your email password for security or infact change it now if its real.

Comment: Many thanks for spotting that - I was in too much of a hurry!

Comment: Follow the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide, which will help you figure out what is causing the hold up - it’s most likely that your ISP blocks outbound SMTP.

Comment: I am using SMTP on this ISP successfully with another application & SMTP.js

Comment: I will go look at the PHPMailer guide again - thank you

Answer (score 1):

- If you are using digital ocean hosting, smtp over ipv6 is blocked. Please check if this isnt the problem.
- Make sure you allow insecure applications in Gmail: https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/6260879?hl=en

Also, please share your error log.

Comment: Yes... Gmail change has been made... where will I find the error log? Tx

Comment: When using PHP on unix you may find it in /var/log/. @Bootneck